# Problem with ComponentMeasurements and property "Centroid"

Tags: image-processing, image, segmentation

I am showing here three test images to investigate the output of `ComponentMeasurements` when using the property `"Centroid"`.

`image1` contains a single pixel, of which the center of mass coordinate is detected at `{1.5, 7.5}`.
`image2` contains a single pixel, of which the center of mass coordinate is detected at `{2.5, 7.5}`.

`image3` contains both pixels of `image1` and `image2`. The detected center of mass coordinate is `{2., 7.5}`. This is only the mean coordinate without weighting with the brightness.

To calculate the **center of mass coordinate** of `image3` I would do the following:

```
1/(0.9 + 0.8)*(0.9*{1.5, 7.5} + 0.8*{2.5, 7.5})
```

which gives:

```
{1.97059, 7.5}
```

**Question**: I do not understand the how the center of mass is calculated by `ComponentMeasurements[..., {"Centroid"}]]?`

Image 1:

```
imageData = Array[0 &, {10, 10}];
imageData[[3, 2]] = 0.9;
image = Image[imageData];

binImage = Binarize[image, 0.1]; 
image1 = ImageMultiply[image, binImage]; 
centerOfMassPos = ComponentMeasurements[image1, {"Centroid"}]

{1 -> {{1.5, 7.5}}}
```

Image 2:

```
imageData = Array[0 &, {10, 10}];
imageData[[3, 3]] = 0.8;
image = Image[imageData];

binImage = Binarize[image, 0.1]; 
image2= ImageMultiply[image, binImage]; 
centerOfMassPos = ComponentMeasurements[image2, {"Centroid"}]

{1 -> {{2.5, 7.5}}}
```

Combined image:

```
imageData = Array[0 &, {10, 10}];
imageData[[3, 2]] = 0.9;
imageData[[3, 3]] = 0.8;
image = Image[imageData];

binImage = Binarize[image, 0.1]; 
image3 = ImageMultiply[image, binImage]; 
centerOfMassPos = ComponentMeasurements[image3, {"Centroid"}]

{1 -> {{2., 7.5}}}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `IntensityCentroid` instead of `Centroid`? Not everyone has images where intensity-weighted mean makes sense - think RGB images.

Comment: yes ... thank you ... I find the the help description nevertheless misleading `Centroid properties: "Centroid": center of mass coordinates`.

Comment: Should I delete the question?

Comment: @mrz I think it would be more useful if you wrote a self answer showcasing the use of `ImageCentroid` for future reference. Other people may be as confused by the description as you found yourself to be.

Comment: I support @MarcoB completely and would require a response from you as very worthy.

Answer (score 3):

Just to save the solution for posterity:

As [nikie suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113546/problem-with-componentmeasurements-and-property-centroid#comment308251_113546) in comments, you are looking for `"IntensityCentroid"` rather than the simple `"Centroid"` property to use in [`ComponentMeasurements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComponentMeasurements.html). You can find it in the "Details" section of the documentation of the latter function, under "Spatial intensity measurements".

In the help description (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComponentMeasurements.html) one finds the following misleading text: "**Centroid properties: "Centroid": center of mass coordinates".**

The expression **center of mass** (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass) describes a "unique point at the center of a distribution of mass in space that has the property that the weighted position vectors relative to this point sum to zero".

For an gray scale image the center of mass means the **center of brightness** which has to include the weighting of each pixel with its brightness.